# Access scores for observation on linear discriminants in LDA using MASS:lda()

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

```
library(MASS)
example(lda)
plot(z)
```

How can I access all the points in z? I want to know the values of every point along LD1 and LD2 depending on their Sp (c,s,v).

Comment: Re edit on tags: The 'lda' tag got taken by a text analysis method with the same acronym (LDA) as linear discriminant analysis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is computed as part of the `predict()` method of objects of class `"lda"` (see `?predict.lda`). It is returned as component `x` of the object produced by `predict(z)`:

```
## follow example from ?lda
Iris <- data.frame(rbind(iris3[,,1], iris3[,,2], iris3[,,3]),
                   Sp = rep(c("s","c","v"), rep(50,3)))
set.seed(1) ## remove this line if you want it to be pseudo random
train <- sample(1:150, 75)
table(Iris$Sp[train])
## your answer may differ
##  c  s  v
## 22 23 30
z <- lda(Sp ~ ., Iris, prior = c(1,1,1)/3, subset = train)

## get the whole prediction object
pred <- predict(z)
## show first few sample scores on LDs
head(z$x)
```

the last line shows the first few rows of the object scores on the linear discriminants

```
> head(pred$x)
          LD1        LD2
40  -8.334664  0.1348578
56   2.462821 -1.5758927
85   2.998319 -0.6648073
134  4.030165 -1.4724530
30  -7.511226 -0.6519301
131  6.779570 -0.8675742
```

These scores can be plotted like so

```
plot(LD2 ~ LD1, data = pred$x)
```

producing the following plot (for this training sample!)

[image: lda scores plot]

Comment: Quite useful and then so simple that I can't beleive I had not seen that before. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you calling the function `plot(z)`, you are actually calling the function `plot.lda` - this is an S3 method. Basically, the object `z` has class `lda`:

```
class(z)
```

We can look at the actual function that is being used:

```
getS3method("plot", "lda")
```

This turns out to be rather involved. But the key points are:

```
x = z
Terms <- x$terms
data <- model.frame(x)
X <- model.matrix(delete.response(Terms), data)
g <- model.response(data)
xint <- match("(Intercept)", colnames(X), nomatch = 0L)
X <- X[, -xint, drop = FALSE]
means <- colMeans(x$means)
X <- scale(X, center = means, scale = FALSE) %*% x$scaling
```

We can no plot as before:

```
plot(X[,1], X[,2])
```

**Proviso** There might well be an easier way of getting what you want - I just don't know  the `lda` function.

Comment: +1 and the extra magic source is that this is done for you in the `predict()` method of `"lda"` objects, and then some as it provides several different ways to generate the predictions. I have supplied an example in my answer.

Comment: `predict` - I should have guessed. Definitely the correct way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Some more details to the nice example by [GavinSimpson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/429846/gavin-simpson)

```
## follow example from ?lda
Iris <- data.frame(rbind(iris3[,,1], iris3[,,2], iris3[,,3]),
                   Sp = rep(c("s","c","v"), rep(50,3)))
set.seed(1)
train <- sample(1:150, 75)
z <- lda(Iris[train,-5], grouping = Iris[train,5], prior = c(1,1,1)/3)

## get the whole prediction object
pred <- predict(z)
```

If you want to understand the magic of `predict.lda`, here is how you can calculate (predict) the matrix of LD scores by hand: All you have to do is to center the original data (or new data of the same kind) using the centering vector (LDA uses the mean of group means) of the original data `colMeans(z$means)` and multiply each centered observation by the LD loadings (linear coefficients) stored in `z$scaling`.

**Predict by hand**

```
pred.self <- scale(Iris[train,-5], center = colMeans(z$means), scale = FALSE) %*% z$scaling
```

**Verify using `predict.lda()`**

```
> all.equal(pred$x, pred.self) # it's the same!
[1] TRUE
```

**Verify using `plot.lda()`**

```
plot(z, dimen = 2)
points(pred.self, col = "blue") # corresponds to plot.lda() output
```

[image output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sF6w.png)

A closer look at the `predict.lda` function

```
getAnywhere(predict.lda)
```

reveals that since neither the input data nor the LD scores are stored in the `lda` object, the `predict.lda` function has to look for the input data in the R environment.

```
newdata <- eval.parent(z$call$x)
all.equal(newdata, Iris[train,-5]) # it's the same!
```